# Asp.net Core - pasar modelo del view al controlador

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

tengo un controlador que envia un modelo al View, puede tener hasta 20 registros.
Como puedo hacer para pasar todo ese modelo nuevamente a mi controlador. Lo que pasa es que el usuario revisa ese detalle y al darle grabar tengo que guardar todos esos registros en otra tabla.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace algunas semanas escribí sobre ello:
http://www.jorgelevy.com/post-de-una-lista-de-objetos-al-controlador/

Básicamente el truco está en usar un ciclo for en la página razor, y en el post de la página recibir una lista.

Vista:

```
@model List<ModelListBinding.Models.Person>

<form asp-action="Save" method="post" role="form">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><label asp-for="@Model[0].FirstName" class="control-label"></label></th>
                <th><label asp-for="@Model[0].LastName" class="control-label"></label></th>
                <th><label asp-for="@Model[0].Birthday" class="control-label"></label></th>
                <th><label asp-for="@Model[0].IsActive" class="control-label"></label></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].id" type="hidden" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].FirstName" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].LastName" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Birthday" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="@Model[i].IsActive" />
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

Controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save(List<Person> model)
{
    //Manipular datos
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: gracias KodiakMx me ayudo bastante pude resolver mi problema, solo una consulta si le pongo el atributo disabled al input ese campo pasa como null al controlador. Hay una manera de hacer que no se pueda editar estos input.

Comment: @ManuelSanchez esa es una restricción del html mas que de mvc. Lo que se hace tradicionalmente es modificar el atributo del elemento a enabled con javascript cuando se está haciendo el submit de la forma. Creo que existe otra forma de bloquear el campo sin tener que deshabilitarlo como tal, pero no tengo a la mano esa información. Creo es por css.